# Outer regularity of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

I have proved that the Lebesgue measure, $\lambda$,  on $\mathbb{R}$ is outer regular. By this, it is meant that for any $\lambda$-measurable set, $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\lambda (U)=\inf\{\lambda(A): U \subset A ,A \text{ is open}\}$. However, in the proof I did not use the fact that the set is $\lambda$-measurable. Is this necessary, or is this fact true for all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I realise I may have been unclear, sorry. I mean, is the following true, for any subset of the reals, U, and the outer measure $\lambda * : \lambda * (U)=inf\{\lambda *(A): U \subset A ,A-open\}$

Answer (score 1):

The proof goes as follows;

Let $U$ be a measurable and let $\epsilon > 0$ and we first assume that the outer measure of $U$ is finite. By definition of outer measure we have that  $\exists \{I_k\}$ a countable collection of open intervals which covers $U$ such that 
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{m(I_k)} < m^*(U)+\epsilon$. Define $O=\bigcup_k{I_k}$. Then we have that $O$ is open and $U \subset O$.

By monotonicity we have that 
$m^*(O) \leq m^*(U)+ \epsilon$, moreover, $m^*(O)-m^*(U) < \epsilon$.

By the measurability of $U$ and it having finite measure, by the excision property we have that $m^*(O-U)=m^*(O)-m^*(U)< \epsilon$ hence that $m$ is outer regular.

This process can easily be extrapolated to the case that U has infinite measure by since $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M},m)$ is a sigma finite measure space. (If you would like I am more than willing to fill in the details).

Comment: I did not use this property in my proof. So this is what I did: Take a set A. For all $\epsilon$ there exists $\{(a_n,b_n)\}$ such that $A \subset U = \bigcup (a_n,b_n)$. So we have $ \lambda(U) \ge \lambda(A) \ge \sum (b_n - a_n) - \epsilon \ge \lambda(U) - \epsilon $. The first inequality follows from monotonicity,the second follows from definition of the Lebesgue outer measure and the third follows from monotonicty.

Comment: Yes so what you are concluding after you move you $\epsilon $ around that $m(A)-m(U) < \epsilon$ and you have by excision that m(A-U)=m(A)-m(U) since U is measurable, which gives you that outer regularity is equivalent to measurability.

Comment: Thanks for your replies my friend, but I believe that this property of excision has not been used. I have found confirmation from an online source as well that we have $\lambda * (U)=\inf\{\lambda *(A): U \subset A ,A \text{ is open}\}$ with $\lambda * $Lebesgue outer measure and U any subset from the reals. See prop 6.1 in here: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/3-06-leb-meas.pdf

Comment: Please see edits. You are more than welcome to upload your full solution and I will tell you from that, but from what you wrote in your comment you are implicitly using this property whether you realize it or not.

Comment: Can one one generalise this proof for the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$?