# Karen Saxe Lemma 3.1

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Lemma 3.1**
> If $A \in E$  and $\epsilon>0$, than there exists a closed set $F \in E$ and an open set $G \in E$ such that $F \subseteq A \subseteq G$ and $m(F)\geq M(A) -\epsilon $ and $m(G) \geq m(A) + \epsilon.  $ Where E is collection of all finite unions of disjoin intervals.

The first question why we need this theorem and what it show us?

And the second how it prove?
Because for me it's look like obvious. But i don't know how to start.

Answer (score 2):

First this lemma is not true for all measure spaces, there are conditions that need to be satisfied by the underlying topological space for the lemma to hold. These are quite general conditions, for example any sigma-finite measure on a locally compact metric space.

This lemma is important because it is the key result to show that continuous integrable functions are dense in the set of all integrable functions for the $L^1$ norm. This allows to extend a few theorems in analysis from continuous functions to all integrable functions, by density.

Finally, it is easy to prove for the Lebesgue measure on, say, the interval $[0,1]$, from its very definition, as an infimum of the sum of the lengths of the open sets belonging to a countable cover of the borel set under scrutiny.

As I said, the lemma is true in far much generality, and then the proof is more involved.

Comment: Your answer it's not clear for me can you show the proof?

Comment: See there https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2245426/716791